# How to check if a function is used in a file in PHP?

Tags: php, function

Is it possible to check if a PHP function is **used** in a file?

To be clear: I don't want to know if the function exists in general. I know it is possible to check this by using the build in php function **function_exists**.

I've searched Google and Stackoverflow, but haven't found anything remotely useful.

Comment: A simple search of the file should reveal any places where the function is called.

Comment: Need more context. Is detection code wise or file text search wise?

Comment: Nice question! assuming, you want a summary of called functions in a script. Dont think its possible unless you put a trace in each of your function which is pretty ugly. Depending on the use case, developers use debug_back_trace() or exception getTrace() methods but that helps if you are interested in a single method and want to know how it was called.

The solution is https://xdebug.org/docs/trace.

Comment: maybe you should remove the mysql and file tag. Not relevant.

Comment: Yeah, now that I read this again, I'm not sure if you're just trying to find places in your code where a function is called or to determine whether the function was actually called during the execution.

Comment: @nice_dev: At first, I was thinking of a code wise detection, but seeing the comment of El_Vanja, I guess I should just search the file of a specific text string. The latter feels a bit more 'improvised' though.

Comment: @El_Vanja: I'm just trying to find places in your code where a function is called (written down in the file).

Comment: @f_i Done, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Then IDEs and even text editors can help you. I haven't encountered one that doesn't have a `find` function (even to search across entire folders).

Comment: If you want to see if a function is ever called at -runtime-, you can use the XDebug extension's profiling capabilities to generate cachegrind files for a while (don't leave it on permanently), then search the cachegrind files for the function name. It's a bit more setup and effort, but it will be fairly conclusive as long as it runs long enough and captures all the different usage scenarios. Otherwise, you might have function X that calls function Y, but nothing ever calls function X, and you also have dynamic calls, so code searches can be misleading sometimes unless you're VERY thorough.